# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when using Google place API and Bloodhound

Tags: google-maps, google

My code looks like this:

```
var placesBH = new Bloodhound({
  name: "PlaceNames",
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=180 St Kilda Rd, Melbourne VIC 3006&key=***&" + "callback=?",
    filter: function(data) {
      console.log("data: " + data);
      return $.map(data.results, function(result) {
          return {
            name: results.formatted_address,
            lat: results.geometry.location.coordinates.lat,
            lng: results.geometry.location.coordinates.lng,
            source: "PlaceNames"
          };
        });
    },
    ajax: {
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      complete: function(jqXHR, status) {
        console.dir("jqXHR: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.dir("Status: " + JSON.stringify(status));
        $('#searchicon').removeClass("fa-refresh fa-spin").addClass("fa-search");
      }
    }
  },
  limit: 10
});
```

The result returned by google seems correct but I got the following error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I tried different option: with and without dataType: 'jsonp', with and without jsonpCallback: 'callback', with and without  + "callback=?" at the end of the url, ...

From the console, I got the following:
jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}
Status: "parsererror"

Still got the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid jsonp as the Google API doesn't support that format. To anyway make use of the API, make a server call, not a client call.